# Navbar to fix at the top after scrolldown

Tags: jquery, html

I want my my navbar to fix at the top, after certain number of pixels have been scrolled down. I got this JQ snippet from an existing similar question, but it doesn't work for me. Have I bound it to the right div? Is there a way to do this with Bootstrap exclusively? Just to illustrate what I want, it's in this fiddle (not mine): http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/6/

```
  <div id="nav-wrapper"><!--nav-wrapper-->
        <div class="container"><!--container-->
            <div class="row" id="navigation"><!--header-->
                <div class="col-md-12"><!--col-md-12-->
                    <div class="nav"><!--nav-->
                        <div class="#"><ul id="#"><li id="#" class="..."><a href="...">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6478" class="..."><a href="...">About EFTI</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="..."><a href="...">Our Coaches</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6469" class="..."><a href="...">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6568" class="..."><a href="...">EFTI Forum</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-6477" class="..."><a href="...">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul></div>                </div><!--nav-->
                </div><!--col-md-12-->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!--header-->
        </div><!--container-->
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var elementPosition = $('.col-md-12').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
            $('.col-md-12').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0'});
        } else {
            $('.col-md-12').css('position','static');
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap can do this. They call if 'affix'. Check the documentation in the javascript section on their site.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out. Any idea on what's wrong with my JS however?

Answer (score 1):

I made this function for a website (IDs already adjusted):

```
var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var headerPos = $('#header').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerPos + headerHeight) {
        $('#nav-wrapper').css("top", "0");
    } else $('#nav-wrapper').css("top", headerPos + headerHeight - $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

A live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p86zvs3z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the new `position:sticky`, which will be a part of CSS4, [which can easily be polyfilled](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) to work with existing browsers?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to research that one, can't implement it right away. Any idea what's wrong with my JS code?